# ngFor table pull 5 at a time

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table that as of right now spawns 145 rows, this of course leads to some performance issues on certain browsers / machines. I am looking for an angualar solution to spawn only 4 or 5 rows at a time while perserving the data.

The current table looks like so

```
<tr *ngFor="let point of model.points; let i = index;" [class.isSaved]="point.saved">
  <td style="text-align:center;">{{i+1}}</td>
  <td><input type="number" minvalue='0' maxvalue='360' name="DAY {{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="point.day" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TIME {{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="point.time" [time] disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" [appFixedPrecision]="'3'" minvalue='0.0' maxvalue='359.999' name="AZ {{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="point.az" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" [appFixedPrecision]="'3'" minvalue='-5.000' maxvalue='95.000' name="EL {{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="point.el" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" [appFixedPrecision]="'3'" minvalue='0.0' maxvalue='359.999' name="POL {{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="point.pol" disabled></td>
</tr>
```

psudo code of typescript

```
isScrolled: boolean = false;
  scrollDown() {
    //first pass just physically scroll down to table view
    if (this.isScrolled == false) {
      scrollDown(200, <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById("content"));
      this.isScrolled = true;
    } else {
      //second click dont scroll down, move index from 1 to 5, display another 5 rows to user
    }
  }
```

Am I able to limit this ngFor to only 5 rows of data and change the index to only read x - x+5 or would I have to resort to something more javascripty

Comment: If you created sub-variable that manages the 5 items, and have the ngFor work from that sub-variable instead of the main model.points this will work. edit: I say 5 items, but if you push the items 5 at a time into this sub-variable it will work as expected, and the final result will show all 145 rows.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: iirc PrimeNG Datatable can do pagination for you and lazy load...

Comment: PrimeNG looks like it could solve my issue, but I have a requirement to not include any more packages. I'll take a look at this for my personal project though, it seems really handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did what @Z. Bagley recommended and created a holder array and parsed through X at a time like so

```
<tr *ngFor="let point of displayValues.points; let i = index;" [class.isSaved]="point.saved">
  <td style="text-align:center;">{{(i+1) + displaySet}}</td>
  <td><input type="number" minvalue='0' maxvalue='360' name="DAY {{(i+1) + displaySet}}" [(ngModel)]="point.day" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="TIME {{(i+1) + displaySet}}" [(ngModel)]="point.time" [time] disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" [appFixedPrecision]="'3'" minvalue='0.0' maxvalue='359.999' name="AZ {{(i+1) + displaySet}}" [(ngModel)]="point.az" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" [appFixedPrecision]="'3'" minvalue='-5.000' maxvalue='95.000' name="EL {{(i+1) + displaySet}}" [(ngModel)]="point.el" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" [appFixedPrecision]="'3'" minvalue='0.0' maxvalue='359.999' name="POL {{(i+1) + displaySet}}" [(ngModel)]="point.pol" disabled></td>
</tr>
```

And controlled it like this

```
displaySet: number = 0;
scrollDown() {
  if (this.displaySet < 140) { //my max value
    this.displaySet += 5;
    scrollDown(200, <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById("content"));
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.displayValues.points[i] = this.model.points[this.displaySet + i];
    }
  }
```